# OperationalError in WTForms multiple checkbox

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

I'm new in WTForms and Flask and 
I have a multiple checkbox in WTForms same like https://gist.github.com/doobeh/4668212

```
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
  widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
  option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput() 

class Example(Form):
  toybox = ('A','B','C','D','E')
  toys = MultiCheckboxField(
        'choice!', 
        choices= [(x, x) for x in toybox]
  )
```

I'm trying to choice some toys in toybox. It looks good in webpage but when I submited `form.toys.data` I got  `OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')`

I converted `form.toys.data` to string like `str(form.toys.data)` and it seems like work, but returned string on webpage is  `[u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E']` not `A,B,C,D,E`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where did the error happen?

Comment: `form.toys.data` is a list. What you're seeing is what happens when you make a string out of a list. You probably want something like `','.join(form.toys.data)`. Without seeing what you're doing with it, though, it's hard to say for sure.